# Watir Webdriver Safari : A modal dialog was opened. The SafariDriver does not support interacting with modal dialogs

Tags: ruby, safari, watir, watir-webdriver, safariwatir

While using the watir safari webdriver, the webdriver terminates as soon as it encounters an alert pop-up. Are there any workarounds that will either allow Safari webdriver to function properly with alerts, or to prevent the alerts from appearing at all?

```
    $driver.button(:xpath, "//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-success-red']").wait_until_present
    $driver.button(:xpath, "//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-success-red']").click

    $driver.alert.ok()
  $log.info("create organization successful")
```

error:

> /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/safari/bridge.rb:73:in
>   `raw_execute': A modal dialog was opened. The SafariDriver does not
>   support interacting with modal dialogs. To avoid hanging your test,
>   the alert has been dismissed. For more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3862
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)     from
>   /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in`
>   execute'     from
>   /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:369:in
>   `clickElement'    from
>   /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in`
>   click'   from
>   /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:132:in
>   `click'   from /Users/usr/Documents/workspace/TTQA
>   Safari/tttestlibrary.rb:47:in`create_org'    from
>   /Users/usr/Documents/workspace/TTQA Safari/ttorgusercompare.rb:23:in
>   `org_user_compare'    from /Users/usr/Documents/workspace/TTQA
>   Safari/ttorgusercompare.rb:34:in`'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example implementation:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari
browser.goto 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts'
browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")
browser.button(:text => 'Click for JS Alert').click
puts Watir::Wait.until { browser.text.include? "You successfuly clicked an alert" }
```

You won't see the alert display at all

Answer (score 2):

As described on watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs, you could override the Javascript functions so that the alerts do not appear:

```
# don't return anything for alert
$driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")

# return some string for prompt to simulate user entering it
$driver.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return 'my name'}")

# return null for prompt to simulate clicking Cancel
$driver.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return null}")

# return true for confirm to simulate clicking OK
$driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")

# return false for confirm to simulate clicking Cancel
$driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return false}")

# don't return anything for leave page popup
$driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = null")
```